# No redirect to 503 from the homepage when system is off

Tags: craft3, redirect

When `isSystemOn => false` in the general config; and the user is **not** logged in. Going to the homepage does not redirect users to the 503 template (holding page). All other pages redirect as expected.

Is this normal behaviour or a bug?

*I'm using Craft CMS 3.0.3.1*

Comment: Just saying this because it's only on the homepage: sure it's not your browser serving you a cached version of it?

Comment: I thought the same thing. I tried various browsers, including private modes (Incognito).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on a fresh install of the latest Craft 3 release. Do you have any plugins installed that might be interfering?